# Is there really a timeout for kernels on nvidia gpus?

Tags: opencl, nvidia, gpu

searching for answers for why my kernels produce strange error messages or "0" only results I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988645/cl-out-of-resources-for-2-millions-floats-with-1gb-vram/3992344#3992344) on SO that mentions that there is a timeout of 5s for kernels running on nvidia gpus? I googled for the timout but I could not find confirming sources or more information.

What do you know about it?

Could the timout cause strange behaviour for kernels with a long runtime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Further googling brought up this in the [CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes_Linux.txt](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes_Linux.txt) (Known Issus):

> # Individual GPU program launches are limited to a run time  of less than 5 seconds on a GPU with a display attached. Exceeding this time limit usually causes a launch failure   reported through the CUDA driver or the CUDA runtime. GPUs without a display attached are not subject to the 5 second runtime restriction. For this reason it is recommended that CUDA be run on a GPU that is NOT attached to a display and does not have the Windows desktop extended onto it. In this case, the system must contain at least one NVIDIA GPU that serves as the primary graphics adapter.

**[update]** It seems that the official name for this feature is 'watchdog'.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows Vista or later, the WDDM driver stack will automatically reset the device after about two seconds unless you [tweak your TDR timeouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487368.aspx). (Windows can't tell the difference between a GPU running a lengthy kernel and a GPU that's locked up.) Tesla-branded cards running in TCC mode aren't subject to the normal display adapter restrictions and can therefore run longer kernels.